# Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Chapter 8 failed test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently working on Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial. I've been getting 4 separate errors during this chapter and would greatly appreciate your help with resolving them.

$ bundle exec rake test

```
   1) Error:
SiteLayoutTest#test_layout_links:
NoMethodError: undefined method `full_title' for #<SiteLayoutTest:0x000000049fd568>
    test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'


  2) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_remembering:
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/login"
    test/test_helper.rb:18:in `log_in_as'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'


  3) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/login"
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'


  4) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_without_remembering:
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/login"
    test/test_helper.rb:18:in `log_in_as'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

23 runs, 39 assertions, 0 failures, 4 errors, 0 skips
```

$ bundle exec rake routes

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET    /                         static_pages#home
     help GET    /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
    about GET    /about(.:format)          static_pages#about
  contact GET    /contact(.:format)        static_pages#contact
   signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
    login GET    /login(.:format)          sessions#new
          GET    /login(.:format)          sessions#create
   logout GET    /logout(.:format)         sessions#destroy
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root             'static_pages#home'
  get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get 'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  get 'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  get 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
end
```

test/integration/users_login_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Simulate a user clicking logout in a second window.
    delete logout_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end

  test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end

  test "login without remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
    assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end
end
```

test/test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Logs in a test user.
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
    else
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  private

    # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
end
```

test/integration/site_layout_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    get signup_path
    assert_select "title", full_title("Sign up")
  end
end
```

I made a mess..ugh. Any and all help is much appreciated!

Edit: Also, i'm fairly new to all this, so if I'm supposed to be deleting the old tests as they test GREEN, please let me know. I'm not sure if these failed tests go RED because I'm doing something wrong or if I'm supposed to be deleting them as I go through the tutorial. Thank you!

Comment: First of all, you are doing just fine Philip!  Hartl's tutorial is a great place to start.  Bear's answer is spot on for your routing - you want to Post to create a session.  And to answer your test question - the idea is to accumulate tests and not delete them so that any RED tests help you pinpoint issues in your code (e.g. regressions).

Comment: Thank you steve and Bear! That was such a quick fix haha. The first error is actually due to saving changes from one of the previous chapters exercises, so I removed that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes.rb`

```
get 'login'   => 'sessions#new'
get 'login'   => 'sessions#create'
```

that looks weird. I guess it should be

```
get 'login'   => 'sessions#new'
post 'login'  => 'sessions#create'
```